# How do I remove a Foreign Key from Code First?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localdb

I have two Models. A Bike, and Reservation.

Bike:

```
public class Bike
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public BikeType Type { get; set; }
        public BikeGender Gender { get; set; }
        public BikeSize Size { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public double HourRate { get; set; }
        public double DailyRate { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Store")]
        public int Store_Id { get; set; }
    }
```

and Reservation:

```
public class Reservation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        public int Customer_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }

        public Reservation()
        {
            Bikes = new List<Bike>();
        }
    }
```

When I create the database from Code First it adds a column in the 'Bikes' table called: 'Reservation_Id'.

[Click to view image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYVz5.png)

The problem comes when I create a new Reservation, The bike which I choose gets the 'Reservation_Id' of the Id from Reservation. So when I try to delete this Reservation I get an error:

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
> constraint "FK_dbo.Bikes_dbo.Reservations_Reservation_Id". The
> conflict occurred in database "BikeRental.Model.BikeShopDataModel",
> table "dbo.Bikes", column 'Reservation_Id'.

The code that I use to delete the reservation:
[Click here to view the reservation delete code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJBgc.png)

How can I fix that I can just delete the reservation without interfering with the unique key? Or how do I delete the whole unique key from the table?

Comment: What is the relationship between ```Bike``` and ```Reservation``` ?

Comment: It is a Bike rental so you can reserve a Bike (is this what you meant)?

Comment: im asking which relationship they are having like one-to-one or one-to-many ?

Comment: For my opinion, there is a One(Bike)-to-Many(Reservation) relationship betwen them. to configure that relationship EFCore or EF needs and Foreign Key on the many side. When u didnt define the foreign key on the right side, its blocks to delete action because that reservation object dependent on the bike object. so that means, u need to delete bike first before u delete to reservation. That's why u need to define Foreign Key on the righ side.

Comment: I think a reservation can have multiple bikes (many) and a bike can have one reservation (one). How can I achieve this? Since I don't want to remove the bike I just want to remove the reservation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a One to Many relationship between `Bike` and `Reservation`.
EfCore or EF needs a `ForeignKey` on the `Many` side. When u did not define the `ForeignKey` on the rigth side, EF is gonna block you because that `Reservation` object dependent on the `Bike` object. Your mistake is defining that relationship in the wrong side.

`Bike` class should be like :

```
public class Bike
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public BikeType Type { get; set; }
        public BikeGender Gender { get; set; }
        public BikeSize Size { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public double HourRate { get; set; }
        public double DailyRate { get; set; }
        public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
        public List<Reservation> Reservations{get;set;}
        [ForeignKey("Store")]
        public int Store_Id { get; set; }
    }
```

`Reservation` class should be like:

```
public class Reservation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        public int Customer_Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Bike Bike { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Bike")]
        public int Bike_Id { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: @Wolf I'm glad to hear that, u can accept my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers